# i can't make a listener on my navigation drawer, can you tell me where do i wrong?

Tags: java, android, firebase, navigationview

i create this **`drawer`** from empty activity so i don't use `fragment`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private Button signOut;
private DrawerLayout nDrawer;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle nToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

when i put this `setNavigaionViewListener`, this activity will crash on build, do i wrong somewhere ?

```
    //setNavigationViewListner();

    //get firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

and i don't know why but get current user don't work but i don't get where the error is.

```
    //get current user
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user == null) {
                // user auth state is changed - user is null
                // launch login activity
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };

    signOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_out);
    nDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    nToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this,nDrawer,R.string.open,R.string.close);

    nDrawer.addDrawerListener(nToggle);
    nToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    signOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (nToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//method to set Listener

private void setNavigationViewListner() {
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.account:{
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
            break;
        }

        case R.id.logout:{
            signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            break;
        }
    }
    nDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

//sign out method
public void signOut() {
    auth.signOut();

}
```

Comment: You need to look at [the stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173) to determine the cause of the crash. That said, you're using `R.id.drawer` to find both the `DrawerLayout` and the `NavigationView`. It can't be both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.Yourtoolbar);   
nToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
       MainActivity.this, nDrawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
```

instead of this

```
nToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this,nDrawer,R.string.open,R.string.close);
```

> and also change this remove `DrawerLayout` **`findViewById(R.id.drawer)`** and put Your `NavigationView` **`ID`**
>
> EXample **`findViewById(R.id.YournavigationView);`**

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.YournavigationView);
```

Comment: i put
private Toolbar toolbar;

setNavigationonViewListner();

and change that you told

NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        nToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                MainActivity.this, nDrawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

but not work, am i wrong ?

Comment: yea, i put a toolbar and do it like you sugesst but still did not work    

NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        nToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                MainActivity.this, nDrawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

Comment: @avid_kupit  use this **findViewById(R.id.YournavigationView);** instead of this **findViewById(R.id.drawer);**

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.NavigationView at com.dev.havid.beactive.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56) crash report so long, my be this the main cause ?

Comment: @avid_kupit use this findViewById(R.id.YournavigationView); instead of this findViewById(R.id.drawer);  replce **drawer** with your navigation view id

Comment: NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navid);

still crash, do i have to put setNavigationViewListner(); to ?

Comment: oh check it and start over from the start and it works.